# Click Save to image view controller dismissing from UIActivityController iOS 13 update

Tags: uiactivitycontroller

Need to download or save image to gallery while clicking save to image Presenting UIViewController dismissed after updating iOS 13. Need some solution for this

Comment: i don't get why it's not working when i updated ios 13 after a week it's working